# Could I have answered this any better?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1694625/how-do-i-follow-someone-elses-activity-in-azure-devops-boards/1694640) question was asked, with the key component of the question being

> how do I review someone else's activity?

I answered with a solution, and after receiving comments from the Asker, added another solution.

The Asker marked it as the answer, but only because they appreciated my time. I believe I answered the question well, and the comments tease out detail not captured in the question. See the Askers comments for examples.